# Does FluentValidation have error levels out of the box?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I would like to use the FluentValidation like this:

```
public class CustomValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer> {
  public CustomValidator()
  {
    RuleFor(obj => obj.Prop).NotNull().Level(ErrorLevels.Error);
    RuleFor(obj => obj.Prop).NotEqual("foo").Level(ErrorLevels.Warning);
  }
}
```

Are there any tools for this? The documentation does not contain information about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, the docs don't seem to mention it but it looks like you can use `.WithSeverity(Severity.Error)` where `Severity` is an enumeration (enum) with values of `Error`, `Warning` and `Info`

```
public class CustomValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer> {
  public CustomValidator()
  {
    RuleFor(obj => obj.Prop).NotNull().WithSeverity(Severity.Error);
    RuleFor(obj => obj.Prop).NotEqual("foo").WithSeverity(Severity.Warning);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Note that **Severity is only informational**; IsValid will still return *false* for Warning and Info severity.

Comment: I have already found this enum and was going to answer my own question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Keep in mind a validation with warnings and no errors will still produce _IsValid_ being _false_, which may be very indesirable.

Comment: True, but you could override the `ValidationResult` with custom logic for the `IsValid` property